# Regex expression for strings starting with 0. and ending with ]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, string

I'm trying to use Javascript to split a string of this format:

[[11, 0.8979098920018053], [12, 0.8974489978770909], [13, 0.8969923414600217], [14, 0.8965394942578806], [15, 0.8960900097695623], [16, 0.8956434229475816], [17, 0.8951992496549722], [18, 0.8947569861181227], [19, 0.8943161083767102]]

into separate arrays with only the percentage values. That is, I would like an array like so:

[0.8979098920018053, 0.8974489978770909, 0.8969923414600217, etc...]

What is the correct Regex expression for things starting with 0. and ending with ] ? This is what I have but it is not working:

```
^[0]\.(.*)\]$
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: None of the numbers that start with 0 start at the beginning of the string (or the beginning of a line), so the `^` anchor will definitely ensure nothing matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `JSON.parse` to `.map` into an array containing only the second item of each subarray instead, it'll be far more elegant than using a regular expression:

```js
const input = `[[11, 0.8979098920018053], [12, 0.8974489978770909], [13, 0.8969923414600217], [14, 0.8965394942578806], [15, 0.8960900097695623], [16, 0.8956434229475816], [17, 0.8951992496549722], [18, 0.8947569861181227], [19, 0.8943161083767102]]`;
const arr = JSON.parse(input);
const output = arr.map(([, percentage]) => percentage);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` and `map` - it's better than a regular expression by far:

```js
const string = `[[11, 0.8979098920018053], [12, 0.8974489978770909], [13, 0.8969923414600217], [14, 0.8965394942578806], [15, 0.8960900097695623], [16, 0.8956434229475816], [17, 0.8951992496549722], [18, 0.8947569861181227], [19, 0.8943161083767102]]`;
const parsed = JSON.parse(string);
const percentageValues = parsed.map(p => p[1]);
console.log(percentageValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^` matches the beginning of the string, in your case it's `[[`.
Instead of splitting, you could try to use the regex match against `/(0\.\d+)/g`

So

```
yourString.match(/0\.\d+)/g)
```

Will return an array of the substrings that match the given regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

`(0.[0-9]+)*`

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/e22Zg3/1)

Comment: You should use 0\. instead of 0. otherwise you will match other characters as well such as 0, or every other character